# Angular2 , check or uncheck a checkbox on click of a button

Tags: angular

I have an angular2 application where I want to dynamically check or uncheck based on user action.

This is my functionality,

- I have a checkbox, on clicking this checkbox I ask a user to enter
  his/her email and press a submit button.  After user presses the
  submit button I show a pop-up saying your email has been saved. And I
  hide the text box and the submit button. Along with this I want to
  uncheck the   checkbox that user checked at first place to enter the
  email.

When I try to use this

```
document.getElementById("checkBoxID").checked = false;
```

I get a compilation error

> Error:(33, 60) TS2339: Property 'checked' does not exist on type 'HTMLElement'.

I researched somewhere and found that this property could be 'selected' instead of 'checked', but even that doesn't work.

I can use a workaround of using *ngIf with a Boolean value and get two check-boxes written in my component, one with 'checked' and one with 'unchecked' and render them accordingly based on the Boolean value and keep setting the Boolean value on click of buttons, but I believe that would be the dirty solution.

Angular2 for sure would have something simpler to do this, which I am missing here :(

Answer (score 8):

Two possible ways

```
  <button (click)="cb.click()">toggle</button>
  <input type="checkbox" #cb>
```

```
  <button (click)="isChecked = !isChecked">toggle</button>
  <input type="checkbox" [(ngModel)]="isChecked">
```

[**Plunker example**](https://plnkr.co/edit/C8JYwWNkUVzg6DmzQeqW?p=preview)

Comment: thanks Gunter. 
Your solution will definitely work, in-fact I made it work in a similar fashion. 

<input type="checkbox" id="dep_status_email-alerts" (change)="DepStatusAlertCheckBoxClicked()" [checked]='depStatusAlertCheckBoxChecked'>

And I set the value of my boolean 'depStatusAlertCheckBoxChecked' on my button click.

But I really think that there would be something simpler like setting the proerty checked to true in one of my methods in component's class section.

Comment: Yup, yet another way. I thought of it but wanted to get some feedback first if this is the right direction.